# Getting error while opening the database?

Tags: sql-server

in my system when i am opening the database i get this error like this :

Cannot connect to server\sql2005.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.  When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

can you help me.

Comment: Are you getting this error from SQL Server Management Studio or from within your own developed application?

Comment: Where is the SQL Server instance that you are trying to connect to? Local or remote server?

Comment: which is in our company server Mr.John sansom

Comment: i am getting this while opening the server which is in our company server Mr. Kane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Microsoft Documentation....

[Troubleshooting Server and Database Connection Problems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156468.aspx)